# StopEventually behaves differently in LtxDoc and L3Doc

Tags: document-classes, dtx, l3doc

I was going through two of my own `*.dtx` files and noticed that the content between `\StopEventually` and `\Finale` would be hidden or displayed based on the document class and not on the setting of `\OnlyDescription`. That is the one document using `l3doc` displays the later half of the document while the document using `ltxdoc` does not. I toggled between the classes on both files and the behavior appears to be consistent.

Is it standard for `ltxdoc` not to print out the content between `\StopEventually` and `\Finale` ?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, `ltxdoc` is just a thin wrapper around the `doc` package and the `article` class, while `l3doc` is for now a *much* larger class file. Eventually `l3doc` will be split into a class and a package to document LaTeX3 code, much like `ltxdoc` and `doc` are for LaTeX2ε.

The `doc` package does not define `\StopEventually` directly, but by means of the macros `\AlsoImplementation` and `\OnlyDescription`, which turn on and off the implementation section of the documentation.
When you use `\AlsoImplementation` (the default), `\StopEventually{<code>}` makes it so that `\Finale` executes `<code>` (and checks the document's checksum), and nothing else.
When you use `\OnlyDescription`, `\StopEventually{<code>}` immediately does `<code>\endinput`, essentially ignoring everything else in the current file, which is what you see.

The idea is that you put `\StopEventually{<code>}` between the user documentation and the implementation section, so that with a simple switch you can turn the implementation section on and off.

`l3doc` behaves similarly, except that the documentation should be inside a `documentation` environment, and the implementation inside an `implementation` section. Then, the usual `doc` switches `\AlsoImplementation` and `\OnlyDocumentation` work as usual. Placing the contents inside an environment in `l3doc` makes it so that you have more control over the document, so you have four more switches: `\EnableDocumentation` and `\EnableImplementation` to enable each environment, and `\DisableDocumentation` and `\DisableImplementation` to disable them. `l3doc` also has the `full` and `onlydoc` options which are synonyms for the `\AlsoImplementation` and `\OnlyDescription` switches, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I did not know about `\AlsoImplmenetation` and I certainly did not know about the two environments. Using `l3doc` simply compiled everything; since I was using neither environment. I appear to be using `ltxdoc` properly in but the implementation section is not compiled for some reason, I don't invoke `\OnlyDescription` within the document at all; perhaps i'vé set this globally and forgotten about it, i'll take a look.

Comment: @Carel The default is for the implementation to be printed, so something changed that, somewhere. If you show me the code I can find it out. Also note that you don't _need_ to use `\StopEventually`. If you don't, then neither switch will have effect.